# DataVisualization.Chart, how can I make the X-axis interval larger?

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, data-visualization, datapoint

guys!

I'm trying to build a graph, using Chart from System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting namespace.

I have int values on Y-axis and TimeSpan (converted to string) on X-axis.
But I have too many TimeSpan values (1440 - every minute of a day), so they cant fit one next to another. (sorry for my english). So I decided to display not every time value (every minute), but with some interval (i.e. every 30 minutes or every hour).
The question is: how can I make a bigger interval on the X-axis?
I don't want the labels to be like this: 00:00, 00:01, 00:02, etc.
But I want them to be like: 00:00, 00:30; 01:00, 01:30, etc.

PS: I tried this way, but it didn't work:

```
foreach (var item in data)
{
    point = new DataPoint();      
if (counter % 60 == 0)
{
    point.AxisLabel = item.Key.ToString(@"hh\:mm");
}
else
{
    point.AxisLabel = String.Empty;
}
```

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `Axis.Interval` property in conjunction with the `Axis.IntervalType` property. For example

```
Axis xaxis = chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
xaxis.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Minutes;
xaxis.Interval = 30;
```

should get you the 30 minute spacing that you desire.